# return inserted items for a given interval

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dataset, data-retrieval

How would one design a memory efficient system which accepts Items added into it and allows Items to be retrieved given a time interval (i.e. return Items inserted between time T1 and time T2). There is no DB involved. Items stored in-memory. What is the data structure involved and associated algorithm.

Updated:
 Assume extremely high insertion rate compared to data query.

Comment: It is important to know how this data-structure would be used? Would you have many inserts and/or many queries?

Comment: good question. assume insertions occur at extremely high rate compared to queries.

Comment: @John: define "extremely high rate", if `#insertions=Omega(2^#queries)`, using an unsorted array, and looking for it when asked will probably yield best results. if `#insertions=o(2^#queries)` (note [small o](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) here), then using a sorted Data Structure will probably perform better

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sorted data structure, where key is by time of arrival. Note the following:

1. items are not remvoed
2. items are inserted in order [if item `i` was inserted after item `j` then `key(i)>key(j)`].

For this reason, tree is discouraged, since it is "overpower", and insertion in it is `O(logn)`, where you can get an `O(1)` insertion. I suggest using one of the followings:

(1)**Array**: the array will be filled up always at its end. When the allocated array is full, reallocate a bigger [double sized] array, and copy existing array to it.

**Advantages:** good [caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache) is usually expected in arrays, `O(1)` armotorized insertion, used space is at most `2*elementSize*#elemetns`

**Disadvantages:** high [latency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_%28engineering%29): when the array is full, it will take `O(n)` to add an element, so you need to expect that once in a while, there will be costly operation.

(2)**[Skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)** The skip list also allows you also `O(logn)` seek and `O(1)` insertion at the end, but it doesn't have latency issues. However, it will suffer more from cache misses then an array. Space used is on average `elementSize*#elements + pointerSize*#elements*2` for a skip list.

**Advantages**: `O(1)` insertion, no costly ops.

**Distadvantages**: bad caching is expected.

**Suggestion:** 

I suggest using an array if latency is not an issue. If it is, you should better use a skip list.

In both, finding the desired interval is:

```
findInterval(T1,T2):
  start <- data.find(T1)
  end <- data.find(T2)
  for each element in data from T1 to T2:
     yield element
```

Comment: +1, but I think skip list insertion at end is O(log(n)), because you need to insert the new node in the "base" list and expected O(log(n)) higher level lists. In fact, you can leave off the "expected" here because all insertions are in order - you can make insertion into the skip list deterministic by making the (2*k+1)*2^n 'th element be part of the n most dense lists.

Comment: @ErikP.: Thanks for pointing it out, but I was talking about non deterministic skip list, in which you 'step up' [add a link] with probability `p=1/2` for each level, and that gives you total **expected** number of 'steps': `E(#steps)= 1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/2^logn`. Since `1/2 + 1/4 + .. + 1/n < 2` [2 is the limit in infinity], you get `O(1)` insertion at the end, for non deterministic skip list [on average]. and "expensive ops" are `O(logn)`, which is much better then `O(n)` the array gives. Your opinion?

Comment: @ErikP. and I know also see, that it shouldn't make any difference for making it deterministic, as your last sentence suggests. I think the E(#steps) analyzis above should still apply.

Comment: ah yes - brain fart, sorry. I completely agree with your analysis.

Comment: you keep reallocing the array until you hit OutOfMemory?

Comment: @John: Your question specifically says that the data structure should be in memory, so if #elements exceeds a certain number, you have no choice but to get OutOfMemory. Note that in 64 bits systems, this number is enormeous and usually not realistic [the OS will use swaps to allocate space on disk when physical memory is exhausted]. So, short answer: yes, if you are getting OutOfMemory, you are stuck.

Comment: can we think of some purge mechanism to make it more graceful. we can make some realistic assumptions.

Comment: @John: define graceful. Also, note that in 64 bits machines, the OutOfMemory is expected only after you allocate almost 4 [PB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petabyte) [2^52 bytes] [assuming infinite disk here]. What do you want the system to do when it runs out of memory?

Answer (score 0):

Either BTree or Binary Search Tree could be a good in-memory data structure to accomplish the above. Just save the timestamp in each node and you can do a range query.

Answer (score 0):

You can add them all to a simple array and sort them.

Do a binary search to located both **T1** and **T2**. All the array elements between them are what you are looking for.

This is helpful if the searching is done only after all the elements are added. If not you can use an [AVL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) or [Red-Black](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_black_tree) tree

Answer (score 0):

How about a [relation interval tree](http://dme.rwth-aachen.de/en/research/projects/relational-intervaltree) (encode your items as intervals containing only a single element, e.g., [a,a])? Although, it has been said already that the ratio of the anticipated operations matter (a lot actually). But here's my two cents:

I suppose an item X that is inserted at time t(X) is associated with that timestamp, right? Meaning you don't insert an item now which has a timestamp from a week ago or something. If that's the case go for the simple array and do interpolation search or something similar (your items will already be sorted according to the attribute that your query refers to, i.e., the time t(X)).

Answer (score 0):

We already have an answer that suggests trees, but I think we need to be more specific: the only situation in which this is really a good solution is if you are very specific about how you build up the tree (and then I would say it's on par with the skip lists suggested in a different answer; ). The objective is to keep the tree as full as possible to the left - I'll make clearer what that means in the following. Make sure each node has a pointer to its (up to) two children *and* to its parent *and* knows the depth of the subtree rooted at that node.

Keep a pointer to the root node so that you are able to do lookups in O(log(n)), and keep a pointer to the last inserted node N (which is necessarily the node with the highest key - its timestamp will be the highest). When you are inserting a node, check how many children N has:

- If 0, then replace N with the new node you are inserting and make N its left child. (At this point you'll need to update the tree depth field of at most O(log(n)) nodes.)
- If 1, then add the new node as its right child.
- If 2, then things get interesting. Go up the tree from N until either you find a node that has only 1 child, or the root. If you find a node with only 1 child (this is necessarily the left child), then add the new node as its new right child. If all nodes up to the root have two children, then the current tree is full. Add the new node as the new root node and the old root node as its left child. Don't change the old tree structure otherwise.

---

Addendum: in order to make cache behaviour and memory overhead better, the best solution is probably to make a tree or skip list *of arrays*. Instead of every node having a single time stamp and a single value, make every node have an array of, say, 1024 time stamps and values. When an array fills up you add a new one in the top level data structure, but in most steps you just add a single element to the end of the "current array". This wouldn't affect big-O behaviour with respect to either memory or time, but it would reduce the overhead by a factor of 1024, while latency is still very small.